# Retrive only videoIds from YouTube using API v3

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to fetch YouTube videos based on keyword search.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=eminem&key=YouTube-API-Key&maxResults=5

`items[0].id.videoId` and `items[3].id.videoId` do not exist. Instead they have `channelId`.
So why am I getting channelIds for non-existent videos ? Do I need to filter them manually or is it possible to filter them via the API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to request the id in the part parameter.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&q=eminem&key=YouTube-API-Key&maxResults=5&type=video

Comment: I still don't see videoId for items[0] and items[3]

Comment: For just videos you need to add 'type=video' to the request.